# How to align the button with two labels above and below the input

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently using Bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to align the button with an input that has two labels above and below it.

It works if I put the button outside the form tag but I need to keep it there for the Javascript codes to work.

I've tried using form-inline class and it works well if there's only one label above the input, but if there's another label below it, the button stops aligning with the input.

To get the bottom label to appear, you just need to type a letter in the input and press enter and the button will mis-aligned itself.

I want the button to consistently stay align to the right with the input.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8qlT.jpg)

Here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/rkcmorley/pen/Oeqvdv

Here's the html codes:

```html
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row searchSection">
                    <form id="searchForm" class="form-inline input-group input-group-lg">
                        <div class="col-lg-10 form-group align-self-start">
                            <label class="postcode">Zip Code</label>
                            <input type="text" name="text" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 form-group align-self-end">
                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
```

Comment: The Codepen doesn't seem to demonstrate the issue

Comment: It does demonstrate the issue. Type a letter and press enter and the button won't align itself. You can have a look at the image provided as well.

Comment: so you want to align it on the right section or in the bottom of the form ?

Comment: It should be align to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an empty label to the button's div to align it with the field:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 form-group align-self-start">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I also used `align-self-start` here, same as in the field's div.

Comment: This works well for me. No need to create additional CSS codes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using: `align-self: end` so the button is always displayed in the bottom of the div.

Even if you try to change it to be: `align-self: center` it will not work fine when there is only top label without bottom label: see the image:
[image]

There is a simple solution:
Once the top label is always fixed in with height of 24px, You can also fix the position of the button.

To achieve this, first I removed 'align-self-end' class and  added `.fixed` class with styles:

```
.fixed { 
   display: block !important;
   margin-top: 24px;
} 

.fixed button { 
 line-height: 47px; //because line-height of input is 47px so it'll ethe same height
}
```

You can see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wqmyww) to check it.